# Getting an error in R - [Error: could not find function "qplot"]

Tags: r, ggplot2

Orginal R version

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(ggplot2)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘colorspace’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
> qplot(weights, prices, color = types)
Error: could not find function "qplot"
```

.... Hi got some issues running `ggplot2`, I'm trying to get through a basic online tutorial then the issue, was trying to run the qplot in one of the exercises then i got the errors as listed above, I've read around a bit on previous help lookups, went through the motions of:

- `install.packages("proto")`
- `install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)`,
- rebooting R - still getting the error. Any other "answer"?

@MLavoie, Mike Wise

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Sony/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/ggplot2_2.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1977368 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpY97TTR\downloaded_packages
> library("ggplot2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Sony/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/scales/R/scales.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2movies_0.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-6 plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.3      gtable_0.1.2     Rcpp_0.12.3      grid_3.2.3       munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: what is your sessionInfo()

Comment: Try installing the `colorspace` package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong R version. The output "Warning message: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.3" indicates that R v. 3.2.3 is (or was) installed on your system. I suggest that you try again with R 3.2.3 instead of 3.2.2.

Comment: Really appreaciate your response, just saw it, i feel dumb now going about it... got around it & got another issue now, the packages & library seem to be not at the same place... The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpyeuh7f\downloaded_packages
> library(ggplot2)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Sony/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/plyr/R/plyr.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

Comment: Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question like @MLavoie asked for. This will give us much more insight as to what you are dealing with.

Comment: ive just added, the session info, thanks anyhow, been at it for like 3hrs now - goin around other sites too ... i'll call it a day for now, gonna chase this later... & @ MLavoie @ RHertel @ Mike Wise - appreciate the assistance.

Comment: I wonder if `proto` is screwing things up. The new `ggplot2` doesn't use it anymore I think. At least I don't see it loaded in my session info. Maybe you should deinstall that first.

Comment: try also (re)installing `grid`, `gtable` and `scales` and then restart your environment. I'd also install `ggplot2` with `type='source'` since you're an R version behind.

Comment: Actually if you look at his last session info it looks like he upgraded to 3.2.3. So his R is up-to-date at least. But that is an interesting suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error after installing ggplot2. Two ways around this:

1) You need to load "library(ggplot2)" before you call qplot()

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(factor(CLASS), VOLUME, data = abalone, geom = "boxplot")
```

2) I discovered randomly that adding "ggplot2::" in front of your code also makes it work, without calling the library.

```
ggplot2::qplot(factor(CLASS), VOLUME, data = abalone, geom = "boxplot")
```